# React application don't worl with apollo client, cross-origin error

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

When using apollo client and apollo provider, a cross-origin error is displayed. I read that you need to add **crossorigin** to tag **script**, but there are no  tags in the index.html file. How can this be fixed?
Link to the project on Code SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-smoke-g5f0u

An error is displayed, I do not understand how to fix it
[image]

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./Components/App";

import "./styles.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import Personal from "./Personal";
import Header from "./Header";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://api.github.com/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Header />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Personal} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Главная</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/search">Поиск</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Personal.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class Personal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an react-apollo error !
Your header should be under the BrowserRouter Component

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Personal} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ApolloProvider>
```